# Proving a specific isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

In the category of sets, let $\mathbf{0}$ be the inital object. I want to prove that the projection $p_1: X \times \mathbf{0} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$ is an isomorphism.

So far I have shown the following. Take the unique map $\mathbf{0} \rightarrow X$ and the identity $\mathbf{0} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$, then since $X \times \mathbf{0}$ is a product and maps from $\mathbf{0}$ are unique $p_1 ! = id_\mathbf{0}$ where $!:\mathbf{0} \rightarrow X \times \mathbf{0}$. Now I want to prove that $! p_1 = id_{X \times \mathbf{0}}$, but i can't see how to get it started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can generalize what you want to prove to any cartesian closed category. 
Let $0$ be a terminal object in a ccc $\mathcal{C}$, and let $X$ be any $\mathcal{C}$-object 
Then by definition of the exponential, for any $Y$, we have 
$Hom(X\times 0, Y) \simeq Hom( 0, Y^X)$. But this second set is of size $1$, as $0$ is initial, and so for all $Y$, we have $card(Hom(X\times 0, Y))= 1$. This shows that $X\times 0$ is initial. 
But since it is initial, any arrow that comes from it to itself is the identity (since said arrow is unique, by definition of initial objects). In particuler, since $!p_1 : X\times 0 \to X\times 0$, we have $!p_1 = id_{X\times 0}$

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

In the category of sets, the initial object is the empty set, and $X\times 0$ is also the empty set. You are trying to show that in a category with products, $0\times X$ is isomorphic to $0$. This is not always true, for example, consider the category of groups, $1=0$ is the group which has one element, and for every group $G$, $0\times G$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Yes I know, but my setting is the category of sets, so I don't see why groups are relevant here. I have all the axioms for sets available if that is what you mean.

Comment: Your proof can't be correct, because it would be adapted to prove the same result for any category with products.

Comment: Okay, but it should be possible to prove just using the axioms for sets, I am not claiming it is true in every category?

Comment: The beginning of your proof works for every category with products

Comment: I know that the initial object is the empty set in the category of sets, but it doesn't follow from that without argument that $X \times 0$ is empty for $X$ not empty, i.e. isomorphic to $0$?

Comment: But $X\times 0$ is empty. You don't need category theory for that.

Comment: Okay, if it helps the problem is exercise 6.2 in Lawvere and Rosebrugh, if you have it at hand?

Comment: $X\times 0$ is empty and that's the whole point. The theorem holds in any cartesian closed category, in particular it holds in $Set$. See my answer for details